# Subnavigation doesn't show with the Bartik theme

Tags: navigation

I would like to have a menu point in my main navigation with sub-menu points.

I created a main point *+Services* with two points underneath it where I assigned the respective "Parent link".

The structure looks fine in the administrative interface, but I do not get the sub navigation points to show up or the mother point to drop down even though I selected "Show as expanded".

I placed two menu points under Services that do not show up.

Can anyone help in this matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set it as expandable in structure/menus.